# TortoiseSVN Revision graph fails checkout, etc works

Tags: svn, graph, tortoisesvn, revision, svn-repository

I have a repository on a remote (beyond the firewall) server accessed using TortoiseSVN shell extension. My local coding machine is Windows XP, the remote repository machine is also WIndows based and using svnserve to supply the code, etc.

On my coding machine I can right-click a directory and use "SVN checkout" to retrieve the directory tree from the repository. I can make code changes and commit them.

If I try to use TortoiseSVN -> Revision graph or Show log I get an error message saying "There has been a problem contacting the server" and asking if I want to view cached information. I've tried using Settings -> Saved Data and deleting everything. I've reauthenticated the user/password and saved them.

Any idea why part of the system works? I would think all the paths, authentication, etc would be the same. The problem with the error messages is that they don't say what the problem is or what infomation they're using (eg the path the Revision graph looked at).

Comment: Can you view the full log history?

Comment: From where? If I right click a file and choose "Show log" I get the problem above.

Comment: The revision graph is built from the the repository log, so if neither work it validates that it's a protocol issue.

Comment: Any idea how to test the protocol being used? As far as I know this is set up to use the svn:// protocol ie NOT http/s. From Windows (not Internet) explorer I'm using the Tortoise SVN meny. I don;t see why the menu would be using different protocols for the various (checkout, log, etc) options. NB Checkout, etc works, Revision map, etc doesn't - all from same menu to same repository.

Comment: FYI the remote server is running svnserve NOT apache.

Comment: That is a critical detail that shouldn't be omitted! Edit it into the original post, as it completely changes the answer.

Comment: When I say "protocol issue" I mean that something is blocking some portion of the communication protocol that the client is using to talk to the server.

Comment: Re critical issue I alreay did ("using TortoiseSVN shell extension"). Could you explain how I can read and write to the repository but can't read from the repository using the Revision graph or log. I don't understand how the reading differs (hence how can I test the protocol?).

Comment: Mention **in your original post** that you're using svnserve, not Apache. **This is critical because it changes the troubleshooting steps and answers significantly**. The `svn` protocol is completely different from HTTP(S) and my expectation is that it should either work or not work. You need your firewall/network admin to monitor the traffic & figure out what specifically is getting blocked and where.

Comment: Edited post as suggested. Thank you for  your time on this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your firewall is blocking HTTP methods that pulling the log requires, but checking in/out do no. You'll have to ask your firewall administrator to make sure that all methods [noted here](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#http-methods) are allowed through the firewall when talking to the SVN server.

If you use HTTPS, the firewall shouldn't be able to block any HTTP methods because the method itself is part of the encrypted traffic.

Comment: See my comment under the original question "Any idea how...".